# Linq to Entities : Many-to-Many join a Table and a View

Tags: .net, linq-to-entities, inner-join

I have several tables and a view :

Tables :
- `aspnet_Roles` (with RoleId & other columns)
- `Status` (with StatusId & other columns)
- `RoleStatus` (with RoleId and StatusId and relationships)

When I create the Linq To Entities EDMX file, it creates 2 entities with a `Status` List property in `aspnet_Roles` and a `aspnet_Roles` list in `Status`.
So far OK.

But now I have a view with a `StatusId` column.

What I want is to create a LINQ query with a join between that view and the `aspnet_Roles` table to add a `RoleName` column in the result set.

In SQL it would be something like:

```
Select a.*, aspnet_Roles.RoleName From SearchView a
INNER JOIN RoleStatus ON a.StatusId = RoleStatus.StatusId
INNER JOIN aspnet_Roles ON RoleStatus.RoleId = aspnet_Roles.RoleId
```

But I can't find how to do that in LINQ to Entities.
The problem is that I never have access to `RoleId` or `StatusId` as these fields are "replaced" by the `aspnet_Roles` and `Status` list properties.

So I get a LINQ like that :

```
from avis in ctx.SearchView 
join joinedRoles in ctx.aspnet_Roles
on avis.StatusId equals joinedRoles.Status. (and then what ??)
```

As Status is a list I can't find nothing that matches `StatusId`.

I think I'm doing things wrong but I don't know where.

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend upgrading to EF4; they added "foreign key associations", so we now have the *Id fields in addition to the references.

Secondly, is your view mapped to an entity in the designer? It should be possible to add an association between the view and the Status table. (I have not actually done this with a view, but I believe this would work).

Comment: Hum it seems that EF4 is really cool, but I can't.
Yes the view is mapped (ctx.SearchView).

Comment: Have you tried making `SearchView.StatusId` a navigation property (e.g., `SearchView.Status`?).